# How to create an HTML file with a customized name instead of the default dependency name using maven dependency:analyze-report?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

As we know, the following maven command will generate a dependency-analysis HTML file in the target folder of the module/component:

```
mvn dependency:analyze-report -DignoreNonCompile=true
```

Is there a way to create an HTML file with a customized name instead of the default dependency-analysis name?